# Mismo CSS en distintos navegadores, distintos resultados

Tags: css, flexbox, firefox, chrome

Tengo una lista de elementos que tienen consigo un botón para eliminar.

```css
.container-solicitud-cursos .lista-items .caja-item {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 90% 10%;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #c6c6c6;
    padding: 1.5em 0em;
}

.container-solicitud-cursos .lista-items .caja-item:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
}

.container-solicitud-cursos .lista-items .caja-item:last-child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c6c6c6;
}

.lista-items .caja-item .item-eliminar {
background-color: #d9d9d9;
color: #808080;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
transform: rotate(45deg);
font-size: 40px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 0px;
}

.lista-items .caja-item .item-eliminar:hover{
    background-color: #dedede;
    color: #adadad;
}

.lista-items .caja-item .item-eliminar::after {
    content: "+";
}
```

```html
<div class="lista-items">
               <div class="caja-item">
                <div>
                  <div class="item-titulo">Trabajos de extension en vt (1kv)</div>
                  <div class="item-resumen">2 Empleados / 1º Trimestre 2021</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <button class="item-eliminar"></button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Y veo las cosas diferentes en Chrome y en Firefox:

> Asi se ve en Chrome, es el resultado que yo espero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Asi se ve en firefox, y no quiero esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Probé ejecutar este código en los dos navegadores, desde el snippet de SO y veo el mismo problema, asi que si llevan esta pregunta de un browser a otro van a ver lo que yo veo)

Comment: @Excorpion no, uso css puro. Ya agregué el html.

Comment: @Excorpion además agregué el css correspondiente a las cajas que encierran todo

Comment: Entonces claramente debes tener un problema de compatibilidad en el CSS. Recomiendo hacer un CSS diferente para el uso en Firefox. Funciona en Chrome, Opera, y Edge, pero causa el problema en Firefox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe a que cada navegador, por defecto, aplica diferentes estilos para los distintos elementos.

La solución es unificar dichos estilos, ya sea manualmente o utilizando una librería existente, como por ejemplo:

- [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/)
- [reset.css](https://github.com/shannonmoeller/reset-css)
- [sanitize.css](https://github.com/csstools/sanitize.css)
- etc.

#### Demo:

```css
.container-solicitud-cursos .lista-items .caja-item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 90% 10%;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #c6c6c6;
  padding: 1.5em 0em;
}

.container-solicitud-cursos .lista-items .caja-item:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.container-solicitud-cursos .lista-items .caja-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c6c6c6;
}

.lista-items .caja-item .item-eliminar {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  color: #808080;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  font-size: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0px;
}

.lista-items .caja-item .item-eliminar:hover {
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: #adadad;
}

.lista-items .caja-item .item-eliminar::after {
  content: "+";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/normalize.css@8.0.1/normalize.css"
/>
<div class="lista-items">
  <div class="caja-item">
    <div>
      <div class="item-titulo">Trabajos de extension en vt (1kv)</div>
      <div class="item-resumen">2 Empleados / 1º Trimestre 2021</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="item-eliminar"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Venia a poner la respuesta a mi pregunta, lo encontre en SO en ingles. Definitivamente esas reglas CSS "magicamente" arreglaron todo. Se agradece a todos por su tiempo.